# PowerShell How can I make a parameter optional not adding the parameter if is null to ExecuteSSHCommand

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script with a function like this:

```
function RunOtherScript($_oneParameter, $twoParameter)
{
    ExecuteSSHCommand ("python -u otherScript.py " +
                       "--oneParameter $_oneParameter " +
                       "--twoParameter $twoParameter ")
}
```

The parameter "twoParameter" is optional. My question is how can I add the string "--twoParameter $twoParameter " dinamically depending if the $twoParameter is null or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
function RunOtherScript($_oneParameter, $twoParameter) {
  $cmd = "python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter $_oneParameter"
  if ($twoParameter -ne $null) { $cmd += " --twoParameter $twoParameter" }
  ExecuteSSHCommand $cmd
}
```

Comment: question, this "python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter $_oneParameter" it should not be "python -u otherScript.py" + "oneParameter $_oneParameter" ?

Comment: `"python -u otherScript.py " + "--oneParameter $_oneParameter"` is just a more complicated way of writing `"python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter $_oneParameter"`. The `+` operator concatenates the two strings, so you can just as well make it a single string from the start.

Answer (score 0):

haha, no easy way out of this one:

```
function RunOtherScript($_oneParameter, $twoParameter)
{
    if($twoParameter -ne $null){
        ExecuteSSHCommand ("python -u otherScript.py " +
                           "--oneParameter $_oneParameter " +
                           "--twoParameter $twoParameter ")
    }

    else
        ExecuteSSHCommand ("python -u otherScript.py " +
                           "--oneParameter $_oneParameter ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NB: [@AnsgarWiechers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880788/361842) is the recommended answer.

i.e.

```
function RunOtherScript($_oneParameter, $twoParameter) {
    $cmd = "python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter $_oneParameter"
    if ($twoParameter) { $cmd += " --twoParameter $twoParameter" }
    ExecuteSSHCommand $cmd
}
```

The following are purely posted for academic interest.

---

Here's a solution; but it only works for numbers / is only really here for interest rather than being a good or recommended solution:

(I treat `oneParameter` and `twoParameter` differently below; if `oneParameter` is not there, the call the python still specifies it (just with no value being passed); if `twoParameter` is missing though that parameter doesn't show in the python call).

```
cls
function RunOtherScript($_oneParameter, $twoParameter)
{
    ("python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter {0} {1:--twoParameter 0}" -f $_oneParameter, $twoParameter)
}

RunOtherScript
RunOtherScript "a"  
RunOtherScript "a" 10
RunOtherScript "a" "10" # this doesn't work the way you'd want it to
```

Output

```
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter  
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter a 
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter a --twoParameter 10
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter a 10
```

Another Alternate:

This one's less of a hack, but requires more code; so is probably only worthwhile if you have a lot of parameters:

```
clear-host
function RunOtherScript{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$_oneParameter
        ,
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        [String] $args
    )
    process {
        [string]$cmd = "python -u otherScript.py"
        $cmd = $cmd + " --oneParameter $_oneParameter"
        $args | ?{$_ -ne ""} | %{ $cmd = $cmd + " --twoParameter $_" }
        write-output $cmd #to show what we'd be executing
        #ExecuteSSHCommand $cmd
    }
}
RunOtherScript "one" "two" "three"
RunOtherScript "one" "two" 
RunOtherScript "one"
```

Output:

```
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one --twoParameter two three
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one --twoParameter two
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one
```

or for many parameters:

```
clear-host
function RunOtherScript{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$_oneParameter
        ,
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        [string[]]$arguments
    )
    begin {
        [string[]]$optionalParams = 'twoParameter','threeParameter','fourParameter'
    }
    process {
        [string]$cmd = "python -u otherScript.py"
        $cmd = $cmd + " --oneParameter $_oneParameter"
        [int]$i = -1
        $arguments | ?{($_) -and (++$i -lt $optionalParams.Count)} | %{ $cmd = $cmd + " --" + $optionalParams[$i] + " " + $arguments[$i] }
        write-output $cmd 
        #ExecuteSSHCommand $cmd
    }
}
RunOtherScript "one" "two" "three" "four" "five"
RunOtherScript "one" "two" "three" "four"
RunOtherScript "one" "two" "three"
RunOtherScript "one" "two" 
RunOtherScript "one"
```

Output:

```
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one --twoParameter two --threeParameter three --fourParameter four
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one --twoParameter two --threeParameter three --fourParameter four
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one --twoParameter two --threeParameter three
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one --twoParameter two
python -u otherScript.py --oneParameter one
```